# Multiple react bootstrap popovers for multiple elements

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-bootstrap

i'm calling an API end point that will return an array of elements with react js as the following :

```
const [Versions, setVersions] = useState([]);
useEffect(() => {
    axios.get(`myURL`)
        .then(response => {
            setVersions(response.data);
        })
        .catch((error) => {
            console.log(error);
        })
}, []);
```

After that i'm using a component that will render each `element` in the `Versions` array, and each element has a `react-bootstrap` overlay button as the following :

```
{Versions.map(element =>
    <Row>
        <OverlayTrigger trigger="click" placement="bottom" overlay={popover} target={element.content.name} >
            <Button onClick={() => setIdVersion(element._id)}>Sélectionner</Button>
        </OverlayTrigger>
     </Row>                                        
  )}
```

Here is the `const popover` function that contains the popover elements :

```
const popover = (
    <Popover>
        <Popover.Content>
            {/* SOME OF MY CODE GOES HERE // I LOOP ON ANOTHER ARRAY TO DISPLAY CERTAIN ELEMENTS */}
        </Popover.Content>
    </Popover>
);
```

When i trigger the overlay it works just fine, but the problem is when i leave it open and trigger another one, the popover content changes to the second one triggered, and that goes for all the popovers left open, which means i can't trigger multiple overlays and each popover will have its own data displayed, i believe that i have to give each one of them a `target` for the overlay and `data-target` for the popover, i have tried multiple times but no success.

Is there any other way how to do this ?

Thanks in advance !

Comment: Can you create a https://codesandbox.io/ which reproduce the issue? It will easier for us to help you that way. You don't have all the ajax calls. You can set `Versions` as hardcoded array.

Comment: Was this solved?

Comment: Your 'popover' component doesn't seem to be receiving any properties that would make it show different contents for different items. My suspicion is your 'setIdVersion' function changes some global state which is then used in all 'popovers' to read the same bit of data. But as others mentioned, it would be nice to get a full example.